# Coherent Drive with a Jaynes-Cummings Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics

Consider the Jaynes-Cummings (JC) Hamiltonian at resonance, subject to a constant coherent drive. The full Hamiltonian reads
\begin{equation}
 H = g ( a\sigma_+ + a^\dagger \sigma_-) + \varepsilon(a+a^\dagger)
\end{equation}
At time $t=0$, the system is initialized in the vacuum state, $\vert \psi(t=0)\rangle = \vert0, g\rangle$.

**Question:** What is the expectation value of the annihilation operator, $\langle a \rangle (t)$?

This seems like a fairly easy question, but I am unable to find a proper derivation of this problem. The JC Hamiltonian can usually be solved in the Heisenberg picture by identifying invariants of motion, and by deriving a second order differential equation on $a$. But the same derivation does not apply with the additional drive because I cannot identify any invariants of motion.

$$ $$

**Some attempts:**

- Numerically, I find that in the limit of $\varepsilon \ll g$,
  \begin{equation}
   \langle a \rangle (t) = - \frac{i\varepsilon}{g} \sin(g t), \quad \langle \sigma_x \rangle(t) = \frac{2\varepsilon}{g} \big(\cos(g t) - 1\big)
  \end{equation}
- Going in the rotating frame of the coherent drive, which results in a Hamiltonian of the form $\tilde{H} = H_{JC} + \big(\int \varepsilon(t) \mathrm{d}t\big) \sigma_x$. This does not seem to help.
- Define a new qubit annihilation operator $\widetilde{\sigma}_\pm = \sigma_\pm + \varepsilon / g$, the Hamiltonian then reads $H = g (a\widetilde{\sigma}_+ + a^\dagger \widetilde{\sigma}_-)$ with $[\widetilde{\sigma}_+, \widetilde{\sigma}_-] = \sigma_z$. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

$$ $$

**Update:** In the limit of $\varepsilon \ll g$, I may have a solution. In the Heisenberg picture,
\begin{equation}
 \dot{a} = i [H, a] = -i g \widetilde{\sigma}_-, \quad \dot{\widetilde{\sigma}}_- = -i g a \sigma_z = -i g a + 2i H \widetilde{\sigma}_- + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)
\end{equation}
where $H$ is a constant of motion since $[H,H] = 0$, and such that $H = 0$ since $H\vert \psi(t=0) \rangle = 0$. So, differentiating twice yields the second order differential equation on $a$
\begin{equation}
 \ddot{a} + g^2 a = 0
\end{equation}
and hence the sine function I find numerically (with an initial delta-like kick).